# Get accurate week day name and time using JavaScript from internet not from local system

Tags: javascript, api, magento, timezone

I'm a fresher Magento developer. I wanted to display and use current/accurate day and time in my website.

Currently I am using system time in the website based on which html div are being displayed, which is not right for further since every system date and time are not configured correctly.

I have tried using Google Timezone api, but I have no idea on how to use it. Although it is displaying the country name but how to extract weekday and time from that timezone using JavaScript.

Comment: Are you looking for the week day *in the browser's language*? Basically you need to differentiate between three tasks: 1) determining the current instant in time (e.g. via a web service); 2) determining the local time of that instant (e.g. by using the browser's existing time zone conversion code, once it's been given the accurate time; 3) determining the day of week of that local time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks for the reply

Comment: So what's the answer? Do you need a string value, or do you just need to know the day to make logical UI changes?

Comment: But I don't want to use the local time. What a need is to display weekday, date and time from internet using javascript and html only.

Comment: @pepper, have a look at the answer I have posted. You can get the weekday through the API mentioned.

Comment: You said you were using the Google time zone API - why would you do that if you didn't want the local time? I don't mean the time that the system clock shows, but the local time at the user's location, assuming that at least the time zone is set correctly on their machine. You need to get the local time in *some* time zone - which time zone do you want?

Comment: But assuming the time zone will be correct of user will not be the right way to do.Therefore I wanted to use internet time for Bengaluru,India.

Comment: @pepper, have a look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you want the week-day: very simple. You can first fetch the entire string from the endpoint `http://www.timeapi.org/gmt/now?\a%20\I:\M:\S`. This will give you the **current** time in the form of `<weekday> <time>`.

For example: `Tue 07:17:02`. Now, the Indian Standard Time (IST) is **GMT +05:30**. So, let's extract the details and do some basic math:

```
// ... I am assuming that you've fetched the date using some request and it's not in the variable.

var dateGot = "Tue 07:17:02";
var weekDay = dateGot.split( ' ' )[0]; // Yeah! You can now use the week day.

// Now, you need to add 5 hours and 30 minutes to the second part of 'dateGot'.

// ... time adding routine
var addTime = function ( originalDate, hours, minutes ) { ... }

var currentTime = addTime( dateGot.split( ' ' )[1], 5, 30 );

// Now you can use 'weekDay' for the current weekday and 'currentTime' for the current time.
```

---

[This API](http://www.timeapi.org/) provides a service to get the date-time. A simple example is to wrap it up in jQuery AJAX calls, and then use it.

Example:

```
http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?format=%25a%20%25b%20%25d%20%25I:%25M:%25S%20%25Z%20%25Y
```

Gives

```
Tue Nov 10 06:49:28 +00:00 2015
```

You can hack it according to your liking.

As per your wish, we can have it display only the weekday:

```
http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?\a
```

which gives

```
Tue
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: But I wanted to save this value in javascript variable for further use.How to do that.Can you please give step-by-step instructions.

Comment: And I wanted to use indian standard time.

Comment: `But I wanted to save this value in javascript variable for further use` - read all about it at http://www.timeapi.org/

Comment: `And I wanted to use indian standard time` perhaps momentjs will help with that

Comment: and remember - don't trust the users computer

Comment: @JaromandaX, I was thinking of telling him that, but I thought a little simpler approach will be better. I have broken the code down into decoupled routines, which he can modify to his liking.